# How to get an index of event element in a NodeList with .indexOf

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6

I need to know an index of a target element. My code throws an error. Does not `.indexOf()` work for NodeList?

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

function isFirst(event) {
  // Fine
  console.log(event.target == divs[0]);
  
  // But... Error! Why?
  console.log(divs.indexOf(event.target));
}

divs.forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', isFirst));
```

```html
<div>0</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
```

Comment: *"Error! Why?"* `divs` is not an array and therefore doesn't have an `indexOf` method.

Comment: A nodelist isn't a true array so the majority of array methods aren't available (I think `forEach` may be the only one).

Comment: More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It results in an error because `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a NodeList, not an Array; and `indexOf` – `Array.prototype.indexOf()` – is a method of an Array, not a NodeList, and as such doesn't have access to the `indexOf()` method.

You could instead convert the iterable NodeList *to* an Array using an Array literal along with the spread syntax:

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

function isFirst(event) {
  // Fine
  console.log(event.target == divs[0]);
  
  // But... Error! Why?
  console.log([...divs].indexOf(event.target));
}

divs.forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', isFirst));
```

```html
<div>0</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).
- [Array literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals).
- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).